# rails link to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, controller

```
<td>
  <%=link_to image_tag(phone.image, :class => 'list_image'), :controller => 'phones_feature_controller', :action => 'index', :id => phone.id %>
</td>
```

I want to have an image link to another controller.
This link is in my index page and its controller is `phone`. I have another controller `phones_feature`. I want to have a link to `phones_feature`'s index page

my phones_feature_controller :

```
 def index
  @phones=Phone.find(params[:id])
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @phones }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding controller to your controller name.

```
<%=link_to image_tag(phone.image, :class => 'list_image'),:controller => 'phones_feature', :action => 'index', :id=>phone.id %>
```

check [url_for documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_for)

Comment: is my phones_feature_controller okey?

Comment: Your method looks fine, take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions for an introduction. Remember that you need to inherit ApplicationController.